# How do I read RSS feed after converting it into JSON in React Native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, expo, rss-reader

After failing to understand how to parse an RSS feed in to an array and display it (I'm building/trying to build a simple RSS Reader app), I decided to convert the RSS feed into JSON and read it instead. However, it seems like I've managed to fail that too so please help me.

I used `rss2json.com` to convert the RSS feed into JSON

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      homeScreenStories: {
        title: '',
        caption: ''
      }
    }
  }

  FetchDataFromRssFeed() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i ++) {
          this.setState({
            homeScreenStories: {
              title: myObj.items[i].title,
              caption: myObj.items[i].description
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
    request.open("GET", "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Fnews.ycombinator.com%2Frss", true);
    request.send();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    {this.FetchDataFromRssFeed()}
  }

    render() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Swiper
            cards={HomeScreenPics}
            renderCard={Card}
            infinite 
            backgroundColor="white"
            cardHorizontalMargin={0}
            stackSize={2} 
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      )
    }
  }

  const HomeScreenPics = ([
      {
        pic: require('../assets/images/news.jpg'),
        title: this.state.homeScreenStories.title,
        caption: this.state.homeScreenStories.caption,
      }
    ])

  const Card = ({ pic, title, caption }) => (
    <Tile
      imageSrc={pic}
      imageContainerStyle={styles.imageContainer}
      activeOpacity={0.9}
      title={title}
      titleStyle={styles.title}
      caption={caption}
      captionStyle={styles.caption}
      containerStyle={styles.container}
      featured
    />
  )

  export default HomeScreen
```

***UPDATE***

The error I got was: "Cant find variable `homeScreenStories`"